# Dropdown menu stays open on touch devices

Tags: jquery, ipad, touch, jquery-hover

I have a drop down menu, and it works great except on touch devices.  On an ipad, when you touch one of the menu items, the dropdown appears like normal, but stays there even if you touch someplace else on the screen.  How can I make the menu disappear if you touch elsewhere on the screen?  Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jkfbm/

here's my jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.nav_menu > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".sub_menu")
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({
            height:"toggle",
            opacity:"toggle"
        },600, 'easeInOutQuad')
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not sure if hover is the best method for touch screens. Try focus instead. Because that way when 'out of focus' function should be false. Have you seen the hover function on jQuery? You have two parameter functions. `hover(function(){//in hover},function(){//out of hover});`. 
So you could reverse the animation that way?

Comment: "focus" doesn't seem to work.  I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to javascript, so I might need some code examples to really grasp what you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm attempting to use modernizr to offer an alternative for touch events, but I'm not clear on how to pull that off..

Comment: Correct, dont use hover on touch screens. You should use a tap for both opening and closing navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. I think it's your toggle but then again I could be wrong as you've said it works on other devices and browsers.

```
$('li','.nav_menu'.hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'100%','opacity':'1'},600);//plus I've noticed a syntax error on this line.
//unexpected bracket after 'easeInOutQuad'
},function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'0%','opacity':'0'},600);//putting back the animation.
});
```

I could be wrong but try it out see what happens.

Comment: this didn't work.  The nav menu no longer showed on hover in a regular browser.

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently trying this...better suggestion anyone?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav_menu > li').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).children(".sub_menu")
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 600, 'easeInOutQuad');
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        $(".sub_menu").hide();
    });
});
```